# How do I query one database, if no results returned then query another database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 4 databases with the same table (i.e. same structure). 
The aim is to check database 1 for an ID number, if it exists stop processing and return a name. If the ID doesn't exist in database 1 then check database 2 and so on.

I could combine results using UNION but my goal here is to optimize this process by minimizing calls to subsequent databases if a result is found in the first query.

```
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE1.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
UNION
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE2.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
UNION
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE3.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
UNION
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE4.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
```

Or I was thinking of using four separate stored procedures and attempting something like this...

```
EXEC DB1_SP @DOCID=1, @DOCNAME1 OUTPUT

IF ISNULL(@DOCNAME)
    EXEC DB2_SP @DOCID=1, @DOCNAME2 OUTPUT
ELSE 
    RETURN @DOCNAME1
    EXIT
END IF
IF ISNULL(@DOCNAME2)
    EXEC DB3_SP @DOCID=1, @DOCNAME3 OUTPUT
ELSE 
    RETURN @DOCNAME2
    EXIT
END IF
etc...
```

Has anyone got a suggestion or an alternative?

Comment: If you have an index on `doctable(docid)` in each of the databases, then performance should be very fast -- you probably don't have to worry about  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all four databases are on the same server (as sort of suggested by your naming convention that lacks a server but also a schema), I would suggest just doing `union all`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DOCNAME
FROM (SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE1.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE2.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE3.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE4.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
     ) t;
```

Be sure you have in index on `doctable(docid)` or better yet `doctable(docid, docname)` in all four databases, and performance should be fine for most purposes.

EDIT:

If this doesn't meet the performance goal, the stored procedure can just look like:

```
declare @docname . . . ;

SELECT @docname = DOCNAME FROM DATABASE1.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1;

if @docname is null
begin
    SELECT @docname = DOCNAME FROM DATABASE2.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1;
end;

if @docname is null
begin
    SELECT @docname = DOCNAME FROM DATABASE3.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1;
end;

if @docname is null
begin
    SELECT @docname = DOCNAME FROM DATABASE4.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1;
end;
```

There is no need for an `exec` in the stored procedure to run these queries.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought to check the indexes. Also thanks for simplifying the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

you are using sql-server.
then you can use @@ROWCOUNT.

refference : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx

```
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE1.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
if @@Rowcount = 0
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE2.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
if @@Rowcount = 0
SELECT DOCNAME FROM DATABASE3.DOCTABLE WHERE DOCID=1
```

Comment: there the detail use of @@Rowcount